# Single multiplication makes code ~10 slower in fastmod implementation

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, integer-division

Here is a fastmod wrapper and two operators I've implemented for using it:

```
class fastmod
{
public:
  [[using gnu: cold]] fastmod(uint64_t denominator) : denominator_(denominator) 
  { 
    M_ = static_cast<__uint128_t>(-1) / denominator + 1; 
  }

private:
  friend uint64_t operator/(uint64_t, fastmod const&);
  friend uint64_t operator%(uint64_t, fastmod const&);

private:
  uint64_t denominator_;
  __uint128_t M_;
};

[[using gnu: hot, always_inline]] inline uint64_t operator/(uint64_t numerator, fastmod const&     divisor)
{
  return ((divisor.M_ & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL) * numerator >> 64ULL) + ((divisor.M_ >> 64ULL) * numerator >> 64ULL);
}

[[using gnu: hot, always_inline]] inline uint64_t operator%(uint64_t numerator, fastmod const& divisor)
{
  __uint128_t magic = divisor.M_ * numerator;
  return ((magic & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL) * divisor.denominator_ >> 64ULL) + ((magic >> 64ULL) * divisor.denominator_ >> 64ULL);
}
```

Benchmarking this against normal integer division, I see the following results (compiled with `gcc9.1 -O3 -std=c++17 -c`):

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark              Time             CPU   Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------------------
div_bench           6.19 ns         6.17 ns    113415439
mod_bench           6.18 ns         6.17 ns    113532739
fastdiv_bench       2.06 ns         2.06 ns    340581374
fastmod_bench       25.8 ns         25.7 ns     27230411
```

With the benchmarking code being

```
std::mt19937_64 mt;
fastdiv denominator = mt() % (1ULL << 27);

for(auto _ : state)
{
  auto numerator = mt();
  benchmark::DoNotOptimize(numerator % denominator);
}
```

for `fastmod_bench` and

```
std::mt19937_64 mt;
fastmod denominator = mt() % (1ULL << 27);

for(auto _ : state)
{
  auto numerator = mt();
  benchmark::DoNotOptimize(numerator / denominator);
}
```

for `fastdiv_bench`.

The `fastmod_bench` result is not what I expected. I strongly suspect that this is due to the line

```
__uint128_t magic = divisor.M_ * numerator;
```

since if I remove this and replace `magic` with just `numerator`, the new result becomes

```
fastmod_bench       1.70 ns         1.70 ns    412247047
```

which is over 10x faster than with the multiplication.

I'm wondering why with the introduction of this multiplication, this code runs ~4x slower than even regular integer division. I expected my benchmark to be in the 2ns range, along with the benchmark for division.

I have this loaded into godbolt here: https://godbolt.org/z/4fcAQA, but I don't see anything that quickly explains why the performance nukes because of the multiplication.

---

Unfortunately, it looks like this was a problem with my benchmark; the number generation must be interacting with the modulus somehow. Here's a new benchmark, same compiler/options:

```
std::mt19937_64 mt;
fastmod denominator = mt() % (1ULL << 27);
uint64_t numerator{10001107};
constexpr uint64_t transform{10005731};

for(auto _ : state)
{
  numerator *= transform;
  benchmark::DoNotOptimize(numerator % denominator);
}
```

(Similarly for division.)

I get the following results now:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark              Time             CPU   Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------------------
div_bench           5.22 ns         5.20 ns    134608758
mod_bench           5.22 ns         5.20 ns    134627064
fastmod_bench       1.30 ns         1.30 ns    540373271
fastdiv_bench       1.30 ns         1.30 ns    540333224
```

Comment: its is not clear what times you are comparing. What exactly is the benchmark? What compiler options did you use when measuring times?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Thanks for your comment. I fleshed out the question a bit more. Let me know if there's anything else that is still unclear.

Comment: Title says the code is 10x slower, question says 4x slower. Which is it?

Comment: @Caleb It's >10x slower than without the multiplication. The whole algorithm is 4x slower than _even_ regular integer division, which I added to hopefully emphasise that the benchmark result is not expected. I changed the question to make clearer what I'm comparing as well as align the body with the title.

Comment: You may have to examine the assembly to see what the compiler is doing with your code. From Godbolt, it seems like GCC at least is creating much more efficient assembly for a simple modulus compared to your function.

Comment: @ChrisMM The simple modulus implementation uses `div`, which is the expensive instruction that I'm trying to avoid. I've otherwise looked at the assembly, but it's not clear what is causing issues. Stabbing in the dark, I'd guess some kind of data dependency between the benchmark iterations (?). Ultimately, I don't know.

Comment: A benchmark using a random number generator will be dominated by the time taken to generate the random numbers.  That's generally not a quick algorithm.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, but I think it's reasonable enough to assume it a generally constant cost. The example here is solely to highlight the huge added cost of the multiplication in the modulo implementation.

Comment: I'm merely pointing out that your testing methodology has problems. It's hard to trust a bad test. There's no guarantee that the problem is in your code at all.

Comment: @MarkRansom It hurts that you are right. I changed the benchmark to use a multiplication group to generate numerators and my benchmark is giving me results that I expect now. Lesson learnt.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to `@Mark Ransom` for his suggestion to improve my benchmarks. While this did result in me getting more reasonable numbers, it didn't really sit well with me that the current approach could have such a dramatic impact on performance.

---

Here's a final minimal working example that I used to reproduce the issue and thus attempt to isolate it. I added both the modulus and division benchmarks to highlight the difference: https://godbolt.org/z/BPzM_h.

Looking at the disassembly of the main loop of `mod_bench`, omitting irrelevant instructions that don't alter the control flow:

```
.L23:
        ...
        ret
.L22:
        ...
        je      .L23
        ...
.L25:
        mov     rdi, rsp
        call    std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned long, 64ul, 312ul, 156ul, 31ul, 13043109905998158313ul, 29ul, 6148914691236517205ul, 17ul, 8202884508482404352ul, 37ul, 18444473444759240704ul, 43ul, 6364136223846793005ul>::operator()()
        xor     ecx, ecx
        mov     rsi, r13
        mov     rdx, rbp
        mov     rdi, r13
        mov     r14, rax
        call    __udivti3
        add     rax, 1
        adc     rdx, 0
        mov     rcx, rdx
        [body]
        jne     .L25
        jmp     .L23
```

We can see from that the disassembled loop is for whatever reason encompassing the constructor of `fastmod`, which is absolutely devastating since it contains a call to `__udivti3`. Here's the disassembly for `div_bench`, stripped down in a similar fashion, which has successfully placed the label ahead of the constructor:

```
        call    benchmark::State::StartKeepRunning()
.L35:
        ...
        ret
.L34:
        mov     rbp, QWORD PTR [rbx+16]
        mov     rdi, rbx
        call    benchmark::State::StartKeepRunning()
        test    rbp, rbp
        je      .L35
        mov     rdx, r12
        mov     rdi, -1
        xor     ecx, ecx
        and     edx, 134217727
        mov     rsi, rdi
        call    __udivti3
        add     rax, 1
        adc     rdx, 0
        mov     r12, rax
        mov     r13, rdx
.L37:
        [body]
        jne     .L37
        jmp     .L35
```

Tagging the `fastmod` constructor with the GNU `noinline` attribute results in much better code generation and brings the benchmark to around where I expected it: ~2ns.

Perhaps this is due to how the compiler perceives `__udivti3`? Hopefully somebody more familiar with GCC's inner workings can provide some finer details surrounding the issue.